# How to setup a Webhook on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an application that stores data in a MongoDB collection "x".

I need that when some new data is inserted into this collection, MongoDB sends a post to another application saying "Hey, new data {"something":"ok"} has been inserted into collection x".

Is there a default function in MongoDB to allow a webhook configuration or do I need to run a Node.js server and listen for this "x" collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in webhook option in MongoDB natively. You will need to have some server-side code subscribe to a [change stream](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) and listen to DB events.

However, if you use a managed solution like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database), you could configure a [database trigger](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/triggers/) that can be used (among other things) to notify an external service about DB events. The MongoDB Atlas triggers also use change streams in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MongoDB have their own way to do that. You can check **Triggers**

[image]

Comment: This is a screenshot from the managed MongoDB _Atlas_ service mentioned in the above answer. This is not native to the open-source MongoDB project.